# 24H timeFormat in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I know this is a frequently asked question, I am sorry to ask this again.

I am facing a problem in displaying 24H (military time) for events.

I tried using

```
 timeFormat: 'H:mm'
```

also tried

```
slotLabelFormat: [
                  'ddd D/M',
                   'H:mm'
                 ],
```

Tried something like this as well

```
 views: {
       month: {
       eventLimit: 3,
       axisFormat: 'H:mm',
       timeFormat: 'H:mm'
              }
        },
```

But nothing worked, can someone please tell where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify where you want to display time in that format? In column names or where? "H:mm" with capital H should work for column names.

Comment: I need to display it on the events , something like  "13:15 coding" , but what I am getting is "1:15 coding"

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc:

```
timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
```

You shouldn't use `slotLabelFormat`.

If it still doesn't work, you may be using the wrong view name (you sure it's "month"?) or placing `views:` in the wrong place.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpsg9pa4/

Set up a jsfiddle if it still doesn't work for you after checking the above link.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to set up a fiddle as it consists of many references in my code :( And Yea, it's month and and it's in the right place as well. Because other properties like eventLimit , showWeekNumbers etc; all are working fine. Thanks a lot for your replies! My bad to debug now :(

Comment: Well can you at least copy your fullcalendar initialization code into the fiddle and fork it in order to save it and post here?